# How to import a package on startup in the Julia REPL, if available

Tags: julia

I'd like to import a package anytime I start the REPL.  Placing the following in `~/.juliarc.jl` is a start:

```
if isinteractive()
    using Humanize
end
```

But if I start `julia` on a machine without this package, the REPL fails to start.

So I tried the following:

```
if isinteractive()
    try
        using Humanize
    catch
    end
end
```

but due to Julia's scoping rules, now `Humanize` is not even available in the global namespace.

What is the best solution?

Comment: For anyone coming here post 1.0: note that the location of this file has changed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52175314/where-is-juliarc-the-julia-startup-file/52175490#52175490

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following - bit of a hack until something better comes along in base Julia:

```
humanize_exists = isdir(Pkg.dir("Humanize"))
if humanize_exists && isinteractive(); using Humanize; end
```

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know if there is anything better on the way?  I didn't notice any related open issues when I looked.

Comment: Proposals for something like this go under "conditional modules", e.g. https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/6195 and https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/6884. I think doing python-style try-catch on import will never happen due to fundamental scope rule issues.