# Where is juliarc (the Julia startup file)?

Tags: julia

I gather that Julia used to have a file called `juliarc.jl` that let you specify things that you wanted Julia to do upon startup.  Some time ago, it lived in `~/.julia/config/startup.jl`, according to [this reference](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/26215).  I now have Julia 1.0.0 on a Windows 7 machine, and I have neither the directory `~/.julia/config` nor any files called `juliarc.jl`.

What is the modern way to tell Julia to do some tasks on startup?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The location of files has changed in Julia 1.0 (ref: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/26161)

Now the locations are the following:

- Global Julia startup file: `JULIA_INSTALL_FOLDER\etc\julia\startup.jl` - (where `JULIA_INSTALL_FOLDER` is the place where Julia is installed, for Linux use the same path with forward slashes `/`)
- Local Julia startup file (please note it might not exist): `%HOMEPATH%\.julia\config\startup.jl` (on Linux use `~/.julia/config/startup.jl`)

Comment: Do note that this is mentioned in the "Getting Started" section of the manual [if you search for "startup"](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/getting-started/)

Comment: [Current link](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/command-line-interface/#Startup-file)  to the documentation for Startup.jl file. In my case the file and the folder did not exist (as mentioned in the parenthesis in the second point of the answer) , so I had to create my own.