# What is the option in Julia REPL that allows only a limited output?

Tags: julia, read-eval-print-loop

The result variable is a json-type string, which is very long. What is the option in Julia REPL that allows only a limited output when the variable is this long? DataFrame is originally only partially output. I hope that the general variables will also be output like that.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can overwrite the `display` method for `AbstractString`s:

```
import Main.display
display(x::AbstractString) =
           show(length(x)<=50 ? x : SubString(x,1,50)*"…")
```

Let us test it:

```
julia> str = join(rand('a':'z', 200))
"wcbifwzglgqyenrcdgdxagohlwdoxrrumoaltklkjauptwzrmi…"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know how to keep Julia REPL set up even when you turn it off and on again?

Comment: Put it  into Julia startup file! Here is how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52175314/where-is-juliarc-the-julia-startup-file/52175490#52175490

Comment: I've opened an issue to discuss doing this out of the box: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/40724. The implementation there also avoids being O(ncodeunits(str)), which is important for *really* long strings.